# Python IRC 8.1.1 Invalid Syntax Error with class Connection(object, metaclass=abc.ABCmeta)?

Tags: python, connection, irc, metaclass

In Python, when trying to use irc-8.1.1's example program irccat2.py, I get this error. I can't find it documented anywhere online. Does anyone know what this means, and how I can fix it? Thank you.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "irccat2.py", line 10, in <module>
    import irc.client
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\irc-8.1.1-py2.7.egg\irc\client.py", line 3
96
    class Connection(object, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5):

You installed a package that uses Python 3 syntax, in Python 2.

The package in question supports Python 2.6 and newer, so there is an installation error here. The [package install script](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/irc/src/b6147feabca6c255e32aeee1274427f7d85d391a/setup.py?at=default) uses the `2to3` code translation tool to rewrite code *as needed*, and it appears that that tool was run while not needed, as the [original `Connection` class](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/irc/src/b6147feabca6c255e32aeee1274427f7d85d391a/irc/client.py?at=default#cl-396) uses Python 2 syntax.

Remove the package and re-install it with the correct Python version.